# Counting subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ with a certain quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> $
> \renewcommand\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}
> \renewcommand\calX{\mathcal{X}}
> \renewcommand\diag{\operatorname{diag}}
> $Compute the number of subgroups $L \subseteq \ZZ^3$ with the property that $\ZZ^3/L \simeq \ZZ/3\ZZ \oplus \ZZ/3\ZZ$.

(Source: [pdf](http://mathematics.stanford.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/QualAlgebraSpring2016.pdf))

**My question:** I have reduced the problem to computing the index of the subgroup $$G_L = \{S \in GL(3,\ZZ) \mid D^{-1}SD \in GL(3,\ZZ)\} = \{S \in GL(3,\ZZ) \mid S_{32},S_{33} \in 3\ZZ\}$$ in $G = GL(3,\ZZ)$, where $D = \diag(1,3,3)$. But I have no idea how to compute it, or even describe the cosets of $G_L$. How can I do this? Is this even a worthwhile approach to the problem? A hint to a solution that doesn't go along these lines is also welcome.

---

**How I got here:** First some notation: $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is the standard basis of $\ZZ^n$, and $G = GL(n,\ZZ)$ is the group of $n\times n$ invertible integer matrices.

If $A$ is any $n\times n$ integer matrix, then we can write the Smith normal form $A = SDT$, where $S,T \in G$ and $D = \diag(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ with $d_1 \mid \cdots \mid d_n$, and the $d_i$ are nonnegative; then $D$ is uniquely determined by $A$. So $$\ZZ^n/A\ZZ^n \simeq \ZZ^n/D\ZZ^n \simeq \ZZ/d_1\ZZ \oplus \cdots \oplus \ZZ/d_n\ZZ.$$
Say I want to count the subgroups $L \subseteq \ZZ^n$ with $\ZZ^n/L$ isomorphic to $\ZZ^n/D\ZZ^n$, assumed finite. (In this problem we have $D = \diag(1,3,3)$.) Clearly $L$ is free abelian of rank $n$, so we can write $L = A\ZZ^n$ for some $n \times n$ matrix $A$ (necessarily injective), where the columns of $A$ form a basis of $L$.

If $A\ZZ^n = B\ZZ^n$, then $A\ZZ^n \subseteq B\ZZ^n$ implies $Ae_i = Bv_i$ for some $v_i \in \ZZ^n$, giving a matrix $P$ with $Pe_i = v_i$; this implies $A = BP$. Similarly, $B = AQ$ for some matrix $Q$; then $PQ = QP = I$ since $A$ and $B$ are injective. So now it is clear that $A\ZZ^n = B\ZZ^n$ if and only if there is some $P \in G$ with $A = BP$.

Let $\calX$ be the set of subgroups of $\ZZ^n$ with quotient isomorphic to the finite group $\ZZ^n/D\ZZ^n$; I want to find its size $|\calX|$. Now $G$ acts on $\calX$ by $S \cdot L = SL$. The action is transitive, since for any $L \in \calX$ we can write $L = A\ZZ^n = SDT\ZZ^n = SD\ZZ^n$ for some $S,T \in G$, so $|\calX| = |G:G_L|$ where $G_L$ is the stabilizer of $L$. Now fix $L = D\ZZ^n$. I can describe the stabilizer as follows: For $S \in G$, we have $S \in G_L$ iff there is some $P \in G$ with $SD = DP$. This is the same as $D^{-1}SD$ (working in the rationals) being an integer matrix. More explicitly, if $S_{ij}$ are the entries of $S$ then
$$S \in G_L \Longleftrightarrow S_{ij} \in \frac{d_i}{d_j} \ZZ \text{ for all }i>j.$$

Comment: You seem to be making heavy weather of this. The answer is equal to the number of subgroups of order $3$ in $({\mathbb Z}/3{\mathbb Z})^3$, which is easy to calculate because all of nontrivial elements have order $3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt ah of course: every element of $\ZZ/3\ZZ \oplus \ZZ/3\ZZ$ has order dividing $3$, so $L$ must contain $3\ZZ^3$, and the third isomorphism theorem applies. Thanks! I figured there was probably a simple solution but I missed it.